# Is there a way to fetch the URL of the current google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### Why?

I am trying to send information about spreadsheets to a server, using the =IMPORTHTML() method. And then returning the appropriate response to the spreadsheet (kind of like an API). I don't want to have to mess with log in data so I am going to use the URL of the spreadsheet for a primary key in a data base.

**I know they could just copy and paste their information into a cell and I could use that. But I want this to be ready out of the box.**

This spreadsheet is intended for unexperienced users, and potentially ones on restricted accounts. And so vanilla is best here. But if that is impossible, just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getUrl()` method of Class Spreadsheet.

Example:

```
function getUrl(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
}
```

You might use it as a custom function, `=getUrl()`, among other ways.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl